# How to strip my email from git repository

Tags: git

I want to publish existing git repository on github. I find it unnecessary to provide personal data within git commit logs (name, email). Nevertheless, I want to store history of changes.

How do I strip/replace personal information from existing fully accessible git repository?

Comment: “[…] from existing fully accessible git repository” – it it’s already fully accessible, then the chance is pretty high that someone already got your personal information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `git filter-branch`. For script example check this answer [Change the author and committer name and e-mail of multiple commits in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750172/how-do-i-change-the-author-of-a-commit-in-git).

Answer (score 0):

To remove personal details in log messages, you can use `git filter-branch` with the `--msg-filter` flag.

```
--msg-filter <command>
       This is the filter for rewriting the commit messages. The argument
       is evaluated in the shell with the original commit message on
       standard input; its standard output is used as the new commit
       message.
```

PS: The email address that you have in your public profile in Github ( https://github.com/account ) is only revealed to people visiting your profile. The email address that you use in your commits ( https://github.com/account/email ) which and used to identify your commits is not revealed to public